# Mishna brurah Siman 243:1 - boudaries of Hava'ah - getting paid for Shabbat use

Tags: halacha, amira-leakum

Can someone clear this up for me:

The Mishna Brura in the introduction to  [243](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.243?lang=bi) says that all heter ways to allow the work of schirus (renter) is only permissible when he pays a lump sum including the shabbos sum in one sum.

> לא ישכיר.‏
> דע ששלושה חילוקים יש 
> אחד הוא אריסות ששוכר לא"י שיעשה המלאכה בשדה או במרחץ והרווחים או הפירות יחלוקו.‏
> הב' הוא שכירות שא"י נוטל כל הרווחים או הפירות ונותן לישראל עבור שדהו ומרחצו דבר קצוב לכל שנה. ‏
> הב' חילוקים אלו מותרים בשדה לגמרי ובמרחץ רק מדינא דא"י אדעתיה דנפשיה עביד אלא שחכמים אסרו אלו הב' חלוקים במרחץ משום מראית העין מפני דנקראת על שמו ויבואו לחשדו שעושה בשליחותו.‏
> אבל החלוקה הג' דהוא קבלנות דהיינו שיהיו כל הרווחים לישראל רק שישראל נותן לא"י דבר קצוב לכל שנה עבור פעולתו זהו ודאי אסור מדינא במרחץ דהוי הא"י שלוחו של ישראל וישראל נהנה ממלאכה בשבת דאם לא יעשה יום אחד יפסיד הישראל ריוח אותו יום.‏
> וע"כ אם מנהג רוב אנשי המקום להשכירם או ליתנם באריסות כמבואר בס"ב חזר להיות המרחץ כשדה הב' חילוקים ראשונים מותר והחלוקה הג' אסור.‏
> וכל היתר שכירות דכאן היינו שהוא משכירו דרך הבלעה עם ימות החול אבל ליום השבת לחוד אסור אפילו בשדה וגם נתפרסם זהו עיקרי הדינים שבסימן זה בקצרה:‏

However, he then says in [S"K 3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.243.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that it's assur to have a sachir to rent (pay you a flat out fee) for a couple days because it's going to be sachir shabbos (probably because he'll be renting it from Thursday-Monday and that'll be on shabbos that the sachir is renting it out).

> מפני שנקרא - פירוש דמדינא שרי להשכירו לא"י לשנה או לחודש שיתן לו כך וכך בין יסיק בו הא"י בין לא יסיקנו וכל הריוח יהיה לא"י דאיסור שכר שבת ליכא דהא מושכרת היא לו לשנה ואיסור דאמירה לא"י בודאי לא שייך בשכירות דלנפשיה הוא עושה ואפילו אם יש לו לא"י רק חלק בריוח המרחץ גם כן אמרינן אדעתיה דנפשיה עביד כמש"כ בסוף הסעיף אלא שאסור בכל זה מפני מראית העין שנקראת על שמו של ישראל ויאמרו הבריות דשכיר יום הוא ושלוחו הוא.‏
> ודוקא כשמשכירו לשנה או לחודש אבל להשכירה לא"י לימים שיתן לו הא"י כל יום ויום שיסיקנו כך וכך אף דגם זה אדעתיה דנפשיה עביד מ"מ מדינא אסור דהוי כשכר שבת ועיין לקמן בסימן רמ"ד דדבר האסור מפני מראית עין אינו אסור אלא בתוך התחום של ישוב ישראל:‏

But what's the problem with that? Why does "Havlaa'h" (paying the wages for shabbos and weekday as one sum) only work if it's for an entire year or month? Why not a couple of days? (he left out a week)...

So I just want to know why havlah doesn't work for a couple of days... and why by a couple of days is it assur m'ikir hadin, but for a year or month it is mutar?

Possibly due to maris ayin only applying to a month + ? But either way the goy has to use it for a couple days before it becomes a month... IDK

Comment: Feel free to edit

Comment: Please consider reading this: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1607/15256

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question, but the MB seems to be saying that the difference is if the payment is per day of usage, or of its a flat fee for a month regardless of usage. Since when it’s only a few days, it’s usually based on usage, it looks like schar shabbos, whereas if it’s monthly, not based on usage, it’s havla

Answer (score 1):

Read [S"K 3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.243.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) t again:

> ודוקא כשמשכירו לשנה או לחודש 
> אבל להשכירה לא"י לימים שיתן לו הא"י **כל יום ויום** שיסיקנו כך וכך אף דגם זה אדעתיה דנפשיה עביד מ"מ מדינא אסור דהוי כשכר שבת

> ... if there's no issue of the business being known as belonging to a Jew, then a yearly or monthly contract is allowed.
> But to rent it out for a few days such that he gives the Jew X amount **for each day of use**, is forbidden, as he's paying for Shabbat.

He does not mention the case of a lump sum for a short period. He mentions a lump sum for a monthly or yearly use, and a daily rate for a few days.

Possibly that was/is common business practice - a daily rate up to a month, and then a flat fee per period. (Poskim often use sensible examples. It adds to their credibility.)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is because if you do havla'ah with a person who does work on weekday and a separate work on Shabbos. This doesn't work since the earnings from Shabbos are not contractually combined with the earnings from the weekday. (Commerce And Shabbos By Rabbi Kushner). 
And also tthe Mishna Beurarah says that doing it for a weekend is like Schar Shabbos in S"K 3.